# How to keep an image map from overflowing from a DIV?

Tags: html, css, image-size

I have an image map inside of a div. When I load the page, the map image overflows past the div so I have to scroll to the right of the page. I want it so the image is on the page without having to scroll to the right.

I tried using `img{width: 100%}` but that made the map links unclickable.

```css
.uc {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, red, white, black);
  margin: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 20px 20px 10px #888888;
  width: 25%;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

body {
  background-image: url("back.png");
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

.descrip {
  border-color: black;
  border: 2px solid;
  background-color: white;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>Lesson 2</h1>
  <div class="descrip">
    <h1>Interactive Diagram</h1>
    <p>Click on the below image to explore various parts of the motherboard including: </p>
    <ul>
      <li>CMOS Battery</li>
      <li>SLI Chip</li>
      <li>CPU Socket</li>
      <li>RAM Sockets</li>
    </ul>
    <img src="mb1.png" alt="Motherboard" usemap="#mbmap">
    <map name="mbmap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="220,794, 478, 1668" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_memory"
  alt="RAM">
  <area shape="rect" coords="547,493,1007,743" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Link_Interface"
  alt="SLI Chip">
  <area shape="rect" coords="569,1072, 975, 1468" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_processing_unit"
  alt="CPU Socket">
  <area shape="circle" coords="618,186,64" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonvolatile_BIOS_memory"
  alt="CMOS">
 </map>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="uc">
    <a href="hw4.html">&lt; &lt; LESSON 1</a>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is you changed your image's width without changing the coordinates of your shapes' coordinates.

Basically you set your coordinates outside your scaled image. So, your coordinates are not correct. Say your image was `500x500` and because you set your image width to 100% and the container div `descrip` width was 80% your image will be `400x500` that is your new image dimensions.

In your HTML the coordinates of the first shape were `coords="220,794, 478, 1668"` y1, x2 and y2 are already outside the image so you won't be able to click on it because it doesn't exist in the first place.

So to **solve** this as you already suggested you should set both width and height properties to 100% and change your coordinates accordingly.